# Aseprite build does not go past the cmake stage on MacOs Catalina

Tags: c++, cmake, macos-catalina, ninja

I was trying to install and compile aseprite on mi MacBookPro with macOs Catalina 10.15.6. I installed everything needed for the build, xcode, cmake, ninja, etc. I also skipped the step to build skia by installing it directly from the GitHub and unzipping the macOs build to my $HOME/deps/skia. This is an image showing where the install is
The folder organization

Then, I typed the following commands independetly of each other on my terminal using zsh, Iterm2.

```
cd aseprite
mkdir build
cd build
cmake \
  -DCMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES=x86_64 \
  -DCMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.7 \
  -DCMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk \
  -DUSE_ALLEG4_BACKEND=OFF \
  -DUSE_SKIA_BACKEND=ON \
  -DSKIA_DIR=$HOME/deps/skia \
  -DWITH_HarfBuzz=OFF \
  -G Ninja \
  ..

ninja aseprite  (Could not do this command as previous cmake stage fails)
```

Do keep in mind that I changed OSX_SYSROOT to where my mac os sdk is which is at /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk
The problem is that this is the output that that command gives me

```
simonb@MacBook-Pro-de-Simon build % cmake \
 -DCMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES=x86_64 \
 -DCMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.7 \
 -DCMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk \
 -DUSE_ALLEG4_BACKEND=OFF \
 -DUSE_SKIA_BACKEND=ON \
 -DSKIA_DIR=$HOME/deps/skia \
 -DWITH_HarfBuzz=OFF \
 -G Ninja \
 ..
CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:16 (cmake_policy):
 The OLD behavior for policy CMP0046 will be removed from a future version
 of CMake.

 The cmake-policies(7) manual explains that the OLD behaviors of all
 policies are deprecated and that a policy should be set to OLD only under
 specific short-term circumstances.  Projects should be ported to the NEW
 behavior and not rely on setting a policy to OLD.


-- Symbol prefix:
-- Could NOT find Threads (missing: Threads_FOUND)
-- Found OpenGL: /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework
-- Adding -lm flag.
-- Could NOT find TIFF (missing: TIFF_LIBRARY TIFF_INCLUDE_DIR)
-- Performing Test WEBP_HAVE_FLAG_SSE41
-- Performing Test WEBP_HAVE_FLAG_SSE41 - Failed
-- Performing Test WEBP_HAVE_FLAG_SSE41
-- Performing Test WEBP_HAVE_FLAG_SSE41 - Success
-- Performing Test WEBP_HAVE_FLAG_SSE2
-- Performing Test WEBP_HAVE_FLAG_SSE2 - Success
-- Performing Test WEBP_HAVE_FLAG_MIPS32
-- Performing Test WEBP_HAVE_FLAG_MIPS32 - Failed
-- Performing Test WEBP_HAVE_FLAG_MIPS32
-- Performing Test WEBP_HAVE_FLAG_MIPS32 - Failed
-- Performing Test WEBP_HAVE_FLAG_MIPS_DSP_R2
-- Performing Test WEBP_HAVE_FLAG_MIPS_DSP_R2 - Failed
-- Performing Test WEBP_HAVE_FLAG_MIPS_DSP_R2
-- Performing Test WEBP_HAVE_FLAG_MIPS_DSP_R2 - Failed
-- Performing Test HAS_COMPILE_FLAG
-- Performing Test HAS_COMPILE_FLAG - Success
-- Performing Test WEBP_HAVE_FLAG_NEON
-- Performing Test WEBP_HAVE_FLAG_NEON - Failed
-- Performing Test WEBP_HAVE_FLAG_NEON
-- Performing Test WEBP_HAVE_FLAG_NEON - Failed
-- Performing Test WEBP_HAVE_FLAG_MSA
-- Performing Test WEBP_HAVE_FLAG_MSA - Failed
-- Performing Test WEBP_HAVE_FLAG_MSA
-- Performing Test WEBP_HAVE_FLAG_MSA - Failed
-- Found GLUT: /System/Library/Frameworks/GLUT.framework
-- Performing Test HAS_NO_DEPRECATED
-- Performing Test HAS_NO_DEPRECATED - Success
-- curl version=[7.21.6]
-- LDAP_H not found CURL_DISABLE_LDAP set ON
CMake Warning (dev) at third_party/curl/CMakeLists.txt:562 (if):
 Policy CMP0054 is not set: Only interpret if() arguments as variables or
 keywords when unquoted.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0054" for policy
 details.  Use the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this
 warning.

 Quoted variables like "HAVE_FCNTL_O_NONBLOCK" will no longer be
 dereferenced when the policy is set to NEW.  Since the policy is not set
 the OLD behavior will be used.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
 third_party/curl/CMakeLists.txt:664 (curl_internal_test)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at third_party/curl/CMakeLists.txt:594 (if):
 Policy CMP0054 is not set: Only interpret if() arguments as variables or
 keywords when unquoted.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0054" for policy
 details.  Use the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this
 warning.

 Quoted variables like "HAVE_GLIBC_STRERROR_R_COMPILE" will no longer be
 dereferenced when the policy is set to NEW.  Since the policy is not set
 the OLD behavior will be used.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
 third_party/curl/CMakeLists.txt:673 (curl_internal_test_run)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at third_party/curl/CMake/CurlCheckCSourceCompiles.cmake:16 (if):
 Policy CMP0054 is not set: Only interpret if() arguments as variables or
 keywords when unquoted.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0054" for policy
 details.  Use the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this
 warning.

 Quoted variables like "curl_cv_recv" will no longer be dereferenced when
 the policy is set to NEW.  Since the policy is not set the OLD behavior
 will be used.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
 third_party/curl/CMake/OtherTests.cmake:31 (curl_check_c_source_compiles)
 third_party/curl/CMakeLists.txt:792 (include)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Error at third_party/curl/CMake/OtherTests.cmake:89 (message):
 Unable to link function recv
Call Stack (most recent call first):
 third_party/curl/CMakeLists.txt:792 (include)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/Users/simonb/aseprite/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/Users/simonb/aseprite/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

I have tried for all day to solve this problem. If somebody can help me compile it would be great!

Both Cmake output logs can be found here: https://gist.github.com/NotVeryGoodAtCodingButOk/d929c2f0c76c8290cb98d6875f832104

Folder Organization is the following
[image]

Comment: Please, add the output (the [first link](https://gist.github.com/NotVeryGoodAtCodingButOk/8ef01741101908de7681ef68e1057d7e)) into the question post itself, as **text**. It is a requirement of the Stack Overflow to have all important information in the question post itself, not *linked*. See also [ask].

Comment: Sorry - have not posted for a while